# Group messaging on my iphone 7

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone 7 and i know I am part of two different group messages but I'm not seeing anyone else in the group except the person that set it up. what I receive is a text from one individual when I know that there are at least 8 or 9 people in the group.

Comment: What type of message? SMS?

Comment: Is this a green bubble group chat or a blue bubble group chat? The bubbles are what the texts are written in.